# Script Tags in shopify checkout

Tags: shopify

I'm looking at developing an app for Shopify which will add functionality to a store's checkout page. It would be ideal if the user didn't have to copy and paste code into files themselves hence I was looking at using the ScriptTag API ( http://api.shopify.com/scripttag.html ) to include a custom javascript file.

I've worked through some of the examples on the aforementioned API page and can get a custom script included on every page on my test store except for the checkout page. I've changed the src to start with 'https://' as suggested by the tutorial but my script still doesn't run or even appear in the page source for the checkout.

Does anybody have any ideas how I can get this working for the checkout? Is what I'm trying to do even possible?

Comment: I've just used the json post method as described in the url

Answer (score 10):

The only page of the checkout that script-tags are loaded into is the Thank You page that appears after an order has been completed.

The pages for steps 1 & 2 of the checkout cannot have script-tags added to them for security reasons.

Comment: 9 years later... is this still the case?

Comment: Seems like the one. We are also not able to inject the script in the checkout page.