# How can I make a minor edit to the Shopify checkout.liquid file?

Tags: shopify

I am currently on Shopify Plus. I am only looking to make a very minor edit to the checkout page. When adding the checkout.liquid file to my theme, I get an extremely barebones and un-styled checkout page.

Does shopify make the default checkout.liquid template code available to use as a starting point?

Note - I tried adding the various objects in the checkout.liquid page docs (https://help.shopify.com/themes/development/layouts/checkout-liquid). These got me part of the way there but the general structure of the page is still not quite right.

Comment: Would help if you made some effort to explain what it is you are trying to do. Saying "minor edit" is useless. Saying what you have to work with is bare bones is not helpful. Be specific. What are you trying to do?

Comment: I would like to add some JavaScript to the checkout page that parses any query params that may be present in the URL and injects them as product description line items. Aside from the addition of this JS, I am looking to keep the overall look and feel of the page the same as the default checkout experience.

Comment: ScriptTags are what you are looking for. Allows you to inject JS safely and cleanly.

Comment: It looks like ScriptTags are unfortunately not supported on most of the checkout steps according to this StackOverflow response: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12992056/918060. The ScriptTags API docs also state this saying "ScriptTags... are loaded into the pages of a shop's storefront and in the *order status page* of checkout" (https://help.shopify.com/api/reference/scripttag).

Comment: You cannot mess with checkout unless you are the owner of the shop, and you are on Plus. Target your App wishes appropriately.

Comment: I am both the owner and on Shopify Plus though.

Comment: What makes you think there are query params in checkout? If there is any data in checkout that is interesting, you might be much better off using script editor to manipulate the checkout. By the time you are in checkout, adding line item properties is too late. You do that BEFORE checkout. 

Again, without an idea of what you're trying to do, it is easier to tell you that what you are trying to do won't work.